# returning and passing 2 one dimensional arrays from a function to another in c++

Tags: function, c++11, parameter-passing, multiple-return-values

I have around 5 functions which exchange data among each other, each fuction has to return an array and around two integers. I went through "tuple" but we cant club integers and arrays together and im not very comfortable with "struts".
If i could please be guided of ways of doing the same or passing and returning two arrays ( the integers can be put in an array).
Thank You

Comment: First of all you can't return two values from a function. Secondly if you're not comfortable with structures then you're probably not comfortable with classes either, and if you don't want to use classes (or structures) then you won't getting very far when programming in C++. My suggestion is that you experiment a little, learn a little more about structures and classes, until you are "comfortable" with them. It's not very hard or difficult, and will make your life as a C++ programmer easier and simpler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you can return a `std::pair` or a `std::tuple`, see [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).

Comment: @Quentin It's still one value being returned. It's no different from returning a structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my point is that it being a single aggregate value is a technical detail that is too weak (and will become even weaker with structured bindings) to warrant a strict "you can't return several values from a function". Because, semantically speaking, you can.

Answer (score 1):

> returning and passing 2 one dimensional arrays

In C++, you can only return a single value. You cannot return multiple values, and the value that you return cannot be an array.

> im not very comfortable with "struts" [sic]

I assume you mean *structs*. Well, now is the time to become comfortable, because a struct (also known as *class*) is great way to combine multiple values - even arrays - into a single object that can be returned.

---

Another option is to pass the function multiple references (or iterators or pointers) to objects that the function can modify instead of returning them.